# Unity side bar sticking?

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher

So is the unity sidebar sticking a new feature. I run apps and the sidebar stays over the top blocking access to the app you're trying to run

Comment: Do you mean the launcher? Could you please provide a screenshot?

Comment: Maybe try `unity --reset` ?

Answer (score 1):

I had some sort of problem with chrome (dev) if you press Super/start twice it should slide back hope this work if this doesn't work you could do is open a different program through the dash (press super/start) I don't know why this some happens.